# How do edit a sprite based on its name?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

So in my game i have a function that spawns coins,they are given the name "*coin*", Now I have no way to reference the coins,example to kill them or move them.So what I'm trying to do is make a reference to be able to use in my code to just change its zPosition.

Everytime I run my app and have a function run that uses the *coinRef* [ex. to change the zPosition], the app crashes with the error:

> 'Thread 1 EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)'

Heres my code:

```
let coinRef: SKSpriteNode = self.childNodeWithName("coin")! as! SKSpriteNode

    func hideCoins() {
        coinRef.zPosition = -1
    }
    func showCoins() {
        coinRef.zPosition = 101
    }
    func killCoins() {
        coinRef.removeFromParent()
    }
```

Comment: Where did you initialise coinRef?

Comment: I suggest you add the coins to an `SKNode` container, add the container to the scene, and then access the coins via the container's `children` array.

Comment: Please tell us which line in your code does cause the crash.

Comment: @appzYourLife 2nd paragraph

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided code to show where `coinRef` is defined and how you are adding the coins to the scene.

Comment: Where do coins get made?  Are you just grabbing any coin off a set of coins that get thrown onto the screen?  After you remove all coins, what is suppose to happen?  Is there only 1 coin on the screen

Comment: @PeterL Currently you have one property which can keep a reference only to a single coin. If you want to keep a reference to all coins, you have to make an array of SKSpriteNodes to store all the coins. Note that this is unnecessary for what you are trying to accomplish. You could use [enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:) SKNode's method perform desired actions on every coin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at what you write

> So in my game i have a function that spawns coins,they are given the name "coin"

it looks like there are multiple coins in your scene. As you can imagine a single name `coin` is not enough to univocally identify more then 1 coin :)

We'll need a way do identity multiple coins.

### 1. The Coin class

```
class Coin: SKSpriteNode {
    private static var lastID: UInt = 0
    let id:UInt

    init() {
        self.id = Coin.lastID++
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "coin")
        super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: texture.size())
        self.name = "coin"
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

As you can see `Coin` has an internal mechanism to assign a new `id` to each new instance. You can use this `id` to reference the `coins` in your scene.

```
let coin0 = Coin()
coin0.id // 0

let coin1 = Coin()
coin1.id // 1

let coin2 = Coin()
coin2.id // 2
```

### 2. Managing your coins

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    func retrieveCoin(id:UInt) -> Coin? {
        return children.filter { ($0 as? Coin)?.id == id }.first as? Coin
    }

    func hideCoin(id:UInt) {
        retrieveCoin(id)?.hidden = true
    }

    func showCoin(id:UInt) {
        retrieveCoin(id)?.hidden = true
    }

    func deleteCoin(id:UInt) {
        retrieveCoin(id)?.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

The `retrieveCoin` method returns (if does exist) a coin with the specified id. Otherwise `nil` is returned.

The `hideCoin` and `showCoin` do change the `hidden` property to change its visibility.

Finally `deleteCoin` remove from the scene the `Coin` with the specified `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Initialise `coinRef` before the `didMoveToView` function, and then give `coinRef` its value in the `didMoveToView` function.

```
class scene : SKScene {

 let coinRef: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

     coinRef: SKSpriteNode = self.childNodeWithName("coin")! as! SKSpriteNode
}



func hideCoins() {
coinRef.zPosition = -1
}
func showCoins() {
coinRef.zPosition = 101
}
func killCoins() {
coinRef.removeFromParent()
}


}
```

Comment: Is the project crashing or is it simply not working?

Comment: You are defining a constant `coinRef` which does reference an empty `SKSpriteNode()`. What is the meaning of this code?

Comment: Oops just saw the mistake. What I am doing is initialising coinRef in the didMoveToView with the value that is required. I am declaring it as a class property so that it is accessible anywhere in the class.

Comment: This is definitely a case where the user wants to be using optionals